# Compute Integral of: $\int x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx$

Tags: calculus

The standard $x = a \sin(\theta)$ doesn't work here.  Any tips?

I wish to compare methods for:

1) $\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx$

2) $\int x\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx$

3) $\int x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find integrals 1) and 3) is to substitute $x=a\sin\theta$, while the easiest way to find integral 2) is to substitute $u=a^2-x^2$.

(The trig substitution will work in all 3 integrals, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It works. Apart from constants, you end up wanting to integrate $\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$, that is, $\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 2\theta$.  And then you can use $\cos 4\theta=1-2\sin^2 2\theta$.

Comment: Mind fleshing this out?